# how to prove sub space of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that $C^{2}$ is sub space of the complex numbers field

how can I know if $u_{2}$ is a subspace of $C^{2}$.

Here is an example I can't figure out:

> $U_2={(a-1,a-b) \colon a,b \in\mathbb C}$$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fdl4.png

I know there are 3 demands:
1. that 0 belongs to $U_2$
2. that the sum of two numbers is in $U_2$
3. that multiplication by a scalar is in $U_2$

In the question above I see we have 0 for a=0 and b=0 but how do I prove 2. and 3.?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually $U_2= \Bbb{C}^2$: it can be proved quite easily by double inclusion.

Comment: And $\mathbb{C}^2$ is not a ''subspace of the complex numbers field'' ( but, what is the subspace of a field?).

Comment: can you please explain how?

Answer (score 0):

Take two vectors $u=(a-1,a-b)$ and $v=(c-1,c-d)$ where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb C$.

Then:

$u+v=(a-1,a-b)+(c-1,c-d)$

$\hspace{1.2cm}=(a-1+c-1,a-b+c-d)$

$\hspace{1.2cm}=((a+c-1)-1,(a+c-1)-(b+d-1))$

Since complex numbers are closed under addition, $a+c-1\in\mathbb C$ and $b+d-1\in\mathbb C$.

Thus, $u+v\in U_2$.

Proof is similar for scalar multiplication.

Comment: thank you! that's very helpful.

Comment: it's supose to be: 
a+c−2∈C and b+d−2∈C
right?

Comment: No, not really. We expressed sum $u+v$ as $(x-1,x-y)$ where $x=a+c-1$ and $y=b+d-1$, so sum is in subset $U_2$ if $x,y\in \mathbb C$.